# How to make mailto: links to go to Gmail?

Tags: mailto, brave-browser

For some reason my mailto links do nothing,but however used to go to Gmail. How do I add this back?

For a while it was going to Outlook, but I removed this from the setting handlers. Now it does nothing.

Comment: In 2023, click the double diamond icon in the right of the address bar.

Answer (score 6):

The two following steps worked for me:

1. Remove any protocol handlers you might have here: `brave://settings/handlers` (pasting this in your Brave address bar) and make sure you have "Sites can ask to handle protocols" enabled.

[image: Brave's Protocol Handler]

2. Open or reload a tab where you have your Gmail account open. At the right side of your address bar you should see an icon like the one you selected in step 1. Click on it and allow Gmail to open the `mailto` links.

Answer (score 5):

`mailto` usually goes to your browser's default email client. Maybe try setting Gmail as default email client in your browser?

https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht